# Facebook like button disregarding open graph meta data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I have set up my page with the proper og meta data (title, type, url, image, site_name, admins, and description). I'm routing the like through a like handler that populates the description and link automatically (There are several different things to like on my page). **Facebook's URL linter pulls the proper data when I enter my URL**, however when I actually try to like something it:

1) Asks for confirmation (I think it's assuming I'm trying to likejack).

and

2) Once I confirm it completely disregards all the meta data it knows it has and posts a like on my profile with data that it guesses from the core index title and first p tag instead of the data that's filled in by the link handler.

I know this method works because my coworkers have implemented it elsewhere. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My meta data:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Foo"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://foo.bar"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://foo.bar"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Foobar"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1111111"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Foo Bar"/>
```

Like button:

```
<fb:like href="https://foo.bar" send="false" layout="box_count" width="100" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

Comment: Did you add the right XMLNS to the <html>?

xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you've already tried it or not, but see http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

try to parse your page, if there is any error with Meta tags then this tool will report it..